# Sort 2 dimension array based in 1st column where the value is a 'version-dotted' string JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Let me exemplify.

**Input:**

I have a 2 dimension array:

> arr = [['13.12', 'www.randomLinkHere.com'], ['13.6', 'www.randomLinkHere.com'], ['13.2', 'www.randomLinkHere.com']]

And I want to sort them based on the first column => arr[i][0].

But when I sort them using the simple comparison function (a - b), it returns something like:

> output: [['13.12', 'www.randomLinkHere.com'], ['13.2', 'www.randomLinkHere.com'], ['13.6', 'www.randomLinkHere.com']]

But the expected result must be:

> expected 'version sorted': [['13.2', 'www.randomLinkHere.com'], ['13.6', 'www.randomLinkHere.com'], ['13.12', 'www.randomLinkHere.com']]

Like it was an object.

Reference: [Expected result as reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJnVn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  ["13.12", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["14.1", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["15.1", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["15.3", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["16.2", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["13.2", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["13.13", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["13.113", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["1.2", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["2.2", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["125.2", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
];

const sortedArr = arr.sort(
  (a, b) =>
    a[0].split(".").reduce((acc, val) => acc * 10000 + parseFloat(val), 0) -
    b[0].split(".").reduce((acc, val) => acc * 10000 + parseFloat(val), 0)
);
console.log(sortedArr);
```

Comment: This solution worked! 

Thank you for all the solutions, guys! You are awesome!!

Comment: It might be worth noting that this solution might fail in the (unlikely) scenario that you have a minor version number a bit greater than 100. e.g. if you add `["14.1", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],` and `["13.110", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],` they won't sort correctly.

Comment: I added also some more elements, but I don't understant what did you mean.

Comment: Okay, now I understand... I changed the multiply 100 to 10000...

Comment: Probably not worth worrying about in the real world, but now if you were to add `["13.12.2.1.2", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],` and `["13.12.2.1.1", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],` to the list I don't think it sorts these two entries correctly (whereas it does with the 100 multiplier).

Comment: Actually, more importantly, if you add (to your current list of items with one dot in them) `["1.1.1", "www.randomLinkHere.com"]` it'll count that as the biggest number.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
    ['13.12', 'www.randomLinkHere.com'],
    ['13.6', 'www.randomLinkHere.com'],
    ['13.2', 'www.randomLinkHere.com'],
];

const sortArr = (arr) => {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
            if (+a[0] > +b[0]) return 1;
            return 0;
        }).reverse();
};

console.log(sortArr(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

A version that should allow somewhat arbitrary lengths of version numbers:

```js
const arr = [
  ["13.12", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["13.6", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["13.2", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["14.1", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["13.110", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["13.11.3", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
  ["13.1090.3", "www.randomLinkHere.com"],
];

const compare_versions = (a, b) => {
  const a_parts = a.split('.');
  const b_parts = b.split('.');
  
  for(let i = 0; i < Math.max(a_parts.length, b_parts.length); i++) {
    let comp = +(a_parts[i] ?? 0) - +(b_parts[i] ?? 0);
    if(comp !== 0) return comp;
  }
  
  return 0;
};

const sortedArr = arr.sort(([a], [b]) => compare_versions(a, b));
console.log(sortedArr);
```